# How to dynamically change a WPF control's template using a checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding

I have an error dialog (shown simplified below).

I display the *Report* object in a *ContentControl* to which I have defined a *Template*  *simpleErrorTemplate*.

There is a *CheckBox* on the Window that I would like to use to change the template to/from *detailedErrorTemplate*.  What is the best way to achieve this?

```
<Window x:Class="Core.ErrorDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="simpleErrorTemplate">
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Message}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="detailedErrorTemplate">
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Message}" />
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Details}" />
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding StackTrace}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />         
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource simpleErrorTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding Report}"/>

        <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ChkShowDetails">Show Details</CheckBox>            
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a DataTrigger in the `ContentControl` Style where you bind to the `IsChecked` property of the ChkShowDetails `CheckBox`

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Report}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource simpleErrorTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ChkShowDetails,
                                               Path=IsChecked}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                            Value="{StaticResource detailedErrorTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

**Update**

Complete Xaml example, paste it and try it :)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="simpleErrorTemplate">
        <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T1" />
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="detailedErrorTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T2" />
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T3" />
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T4" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Report}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource simpleErrorTemplate}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ChkShowDetails,
                                                   Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template"
                                Value="{StaticResource detailedErrorTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
    <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ChkShowDetails">Show Details</CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks, I've given this a try though and it doesn't seem to work, the style is not updated

Comment: @chillitom: Did you move the Template from the ContentControl to the Setter in the Style?

Comment: @chillitom: Updated my answer. You should just be able to copy/paste that and compare it to your code to see what you're missing

Comment: thanks, hadn't removed the Template from the ContentControl as you suspected

Comment: Thank you, this helped me giving my custom UserControl 2 different display mode based on its `Orientation`!!! *bow*

Answer (score 0):

This Solution is for  those who are searching for Template swap.
It is simple hope it helps you. Please point out any mistakes.

Just use this code for changing the Template on checkBox Checked Event.

```
 private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate Temp;
        Temp = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("TemplateYouHaveCreated");
        listView1.ItemTemplate = Temp;
    }
```

refer this link for more information

http://developingfor.net/2009/01/09/dynamically-switch-wpf-datatemplate/

Comment: There is also TryFindResource which will return null if the resource does not exist instead of throwing an error.