# WPF - Change Controls based on listviewitem selection. Controls not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controltemplates

I'm trying to update the controls present on my Main Window based on the listviewitem selected by the user, but when the listviewitem selection is changed the controls do not update.

I used this post as reference [How to dynamically change a WPF control's template using a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192055/how-to-dynamically-change-a-wpf-controls-template-using-a-checkbox)

EDIT:  I initially used ContentTemplate but changed this to DataTemplate based on suggestions, however it still is not updating

The XMAL for my Main Window is

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Default">
        <Grid Margin="20,280,0,0" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ERAFileSelect">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="218" Margin="20,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" CornerRadius="15">
            <Grid Name="grdFileSelect">
                <Label x:Name="lblProcessContent" Content="Drag File or Manually Select File" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtEraFileName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnSelectFiles" Content="Manually Select File(s)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Height="45"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FCSFileSelect">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="218" Margin="20,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" CornerRadius="15">
            <Grid Name="grdFileSelect">
                <Label x:Name="lblProcessContent" Content="Drag File or Manually Select Files" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFCSFileName_TQ02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnSelectFiles_TQ02" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Height="28"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFCSFileName_TQ11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnSelectFiles_TQ11" Content="Selec" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Height="28"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFCSFileName_TQ16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,170,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnSelectFiles_TQ16" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Height="28"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <GroupBox x:Name="gbxProgress" Header="Progress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="445" Width="462" Foreground="Black">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbxProgress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="408" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431" Foreground="Black" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Progress.Message}" />
    </GroupBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,513,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="37" IsEnabled="{Binding Properties.StartButtonEnabled}" Click="btnStart_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="177,513,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="37"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="20,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="740" CornerRadius="15">
        <Grid>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment ="Left" Margin="10" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Lib/Icons/User.png" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtUser" FontSize="20" Height="30" Width="200" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,19,0,19"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment ="Left" Margin="443,8,0,10" Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Lib/Icons/Watch.png" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtRunTime" FontSize="20" Height="30" Width="200" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="519,19,0,19" Text="{Binding AppRunTime.TimeElapsed}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="144" Margin="20,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" CornerRadius="15">
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="lblProcessSelection" Content="Process Selection" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <ListView x:Name="lvProcessSelection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="lvProcessSelection_SelectionChanged">
                <ListViewItem Name="itmERA" Content="Expense Reserve Automation"/>
                <ListViewItem Name="itmFCS" Content="Financial Close Status"/>
                <ListViewItem Name="itmPEL" Content="Peel"/>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Properties}" Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ERAFileSelect}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedProcess}" Value="Expense Reserve Automation">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ERAFileSelect}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedProcess}" Value="Financial Close Status">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FCSFileSelect}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel Code is

```
public class MainWindowModel
{
    public ApplicationRunTime AppRunTime { get; set; }
    public LogMessage Progress { get; set; }

    public MainWindowProperties Properties { get; set; }

    public MainWindowModel()
    {
        AppRunTime = new ApplicationRunTime();
        Progress = new LogMessage();
        Properties = new MainWindowProperties();
        Properties.StartButtonEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

With the MainWindowProperties class

```
public class MainWindowProperties
{
    public bool StartButtonEnabled { get; set; }

    public string SelectedProcess { get; set; }
}
```

And within my MainWindow Constructor I have set the DataContext

```
        mainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();
        this.DataContext = mainWindowModel;
```

When the selection from lvProcessSelection is changed the following code is executed

```
        if (lvProcessSelection.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            mainWindowModel.Properties.SelectedProcess = ((ListViewItem)lvProcessSelection.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            mainWindowModel.Properties.SelectedProcess = string.Empty;
        }
```

This will update SelectedProcess within my ViewModel with either "Expense Reserve Automation" or "Financial Close Status"

I know the DataContext is set correctly for my ViewModel (but may not be for the ContentControl) as I am able to update lbxProgress with new messages and update txtRunTime with the application RunTime

However when I change the selection on lvProcessSelection nothing happens; the default controls of ERAFileSelect remains.

Could anybody point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anybody point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Your MainWindowProperties class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise change notifications whenever the SelectedProcess property is set to a new value:

```
public class MainWindowProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool StartButtonEnabled { get; set; }

    private string _selectedProcess;

    public string SelectedProcess
    {
        get { return _selectedProcess; }
        set { _selectedProcess = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information about this common interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Every view model/model that you bind to must implement this interface and raise change notifications for any target value in the view to be updated.

Comment: Cheers that worked.  Any Idea why my btnStart which had its Enabled property bound to Properties.StartButtonEnabled worked when it was changed from true to false?  Just curious really.

Comment: I can't see where you set the StartButtonEnabled property in your code so I can't answer that. But you should implement the StartButtonEnabled property the same way as the SelectedProcess property and raise the PropertyChanged event in its setter if you intend to set it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not using Data template? Data template will work in this scenario.

Comment: Updating ControlTemplate to DataTemplate and then setting the Property="ContentTemplate" instead of Property="Template" within the ContentControl has no affect.  The controls still do not update

Comment: You need to set content property of content control. Content="{Binding}"

Comment: This did not make any difference.  Are the rest of the bindings for the ContentControl right?  Sorry I'm new to WPF.  I've updated the above XAML to reflect your suggestions